# Replace Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I have a drawer navigation with:

```
private void DisplayView (int position) {
   Fragment fragment = null;
   switch (position) {
     case 0:
       fragment = new Fragment1();
       break;
    case 1:
      fragment = new Fragment2();
       break;
    case 2:
       ...
```

From an activity I can throw that fragment (fragment2 for example)? With BeginTransaction?

Thanks

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a fragment and an activity.

Comment: you dont send intents to fragments

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment cannot exist in it's own, eg. without an Activity. It cannot be fired up with an Intent like Activities do. You have to either create a new Activity to hold your new Fragment or replace the Fragment of your current Activity with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start fragment as an activity, they need to be added to activities.

Read more in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367823/android-app-keeps-crashing-with-error-i-think-it-has-to-do-with-preference-f)

Comment: I can work with

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .replace(android.R.id.content, new Fragment2())
          .commit();

And at the end I can share Fragment2 changes to the previous activity?

Comment: I have an activity that contains various fragments in a navigation drawer in one of them there is an intent to an activity and that activity should be an intent to a fragment of the drawer navigation.

Why? Because the fragment navigation drawer is a list of items and I need to select some ID's and return to activity

I can create other activity with another list and make your selection there, just wanted to know how to adapt to a fragment that had already